# I get an error during installation. The specified account already exists

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get an error during installation. The specified account already exists.

[image]

When I use "wsl --set-default-version 2", I see "WSL 2 requires an update to its kernel component. For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel"

Answer (score 0):

OMG!!
I just copied C:\Users\Никита\Downloads\wsl_update_x64.msi to W:\wsl_update_x64.msi

It's working!!